# Data Validation should be pulling based off of previous Options. Returning Undefined

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

The Bid Sheet is ultimately supposed to enable the user to enter the various Options and it will give them a list if Items with those Options. I suspect my attempt to use the same scripting as the single validation Option is insufficient to handle the multiple Options, but I am too inexperienced to know a better path.

Everything works except for this piece. Which returns "undefined".

```
      var cell = ws.getRange(r,OptionDesc);
      var FullOptions = ws.getRange(r, 2, 1, 7).getValues();
      var listToApplyDesc = FullOptions.map(function (o) { return o[7] });
      applyValidationtoCell(listToApplyDesc,cell);
```

I've included the full script and a link to a copy of the Sheet since I'm not confident enough to simplify to the "minimum reproducible example".

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Y0VT3KYD1wbj6QR1gTLepn7KtxU91rQoqRLL2Zg9-FI

```
var mainWsName = "Bid Sheet";
var nameData = "Data";
var Category = 2;
var ManualAutomatic = 3;
var OptionA = 4;
var OptionB = 5;
var OptionC = 6;
var OptionD = 7;
var OptionE = 8;
var OptionDesc = 9;


var ws = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(mainWsName);
var wsData = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(nameData);
var manAutoOption = wsData.getRange(2, 1,wsData.getLastRow()-1,9).getValues();
//Must change getLastRow Column count to include any added Options

function onEdit(e){
  var activeCell = e.range;
  var val = activeCell.getValue();
  var r = activeCell.getRow();
  var c = activeCell.getColumn();
  var designator = ws.getRange(r, 1);
  var designatorValue = designator.getValue();
  if (designatorValue != "x") return;//designator IF only allows the script to run on rows with x.
  var wsName = activeCell.getSheet().getName();
  if (wsName === mainWsName && c === Category && r > 10){
    OptionsValidation (val,r);

  }


}//end onEdit

//OptionsValidation required to clear Option cells on Category change
function OptionsValidation (val,r){
     if(val === ""){ 
      ws.getRange(r,ManualAutomatic, 1, 7).clearContent();
      ws.getRange(r,ManualAutomatic, 1, 7).clearDataValidations();
    } else {
      ws.getRange(r,ManualAutomatic, 1, 7).clearContent();


//Sets a Data Validation Dropdown based off of input from Category
      var filterOptions = manAutoOption.filter(function(o){ return o[0] === val });
      var firstLevelColValue = ws.getRange(r, Category).getValue();
      var filterOptions = manAutoOption.filter(function(o){ return o[0] === firstLevelColValue});
      var listToApplyMA = filterOptions.map(function (o) { return o[1] });
      var cell = ws.getRange(r,ManualAutomatic);
      applyValidationtoCell(listToApplyMA,cell);
      var listToApplyA = filterOptions.map(function (o) { return o[2] });
      var cell = ws.getRange(r,OptionA);
      applyValidationtoCell(listToApplyA,cell);
      var listToApplyB = filterOptions.map(function (o) { return o[3] });
      var cell = ws.getRange(r,OptionB);
      applyValidationtoCell(listToApplyB,cell);
      var listToApplyC = filterOptions.map(function (o) { return o[4] });
      var cell = ws.getRange(r,OptionC);
      applyValidationtoCell(listToApplyC,cell);
      var listToApplyD = filterOptions.map(function (o) { return o[5] });
      var cell = ws.getRange(r,OptionD);
      applyValidationtoCell(listToApplyD,cell);
      var listToApplyE = filterOptions.map(function (o) { return o[6] });
      var cell = ws.getRange(r,OptionE);
      applyValidationtoCell(listToApplyE,cell);
      var cell = ws.getRange(r,OptionDesc);
      var FullOptions = ws.getRange(r, 2, 1, 7).getValues();
      var listToApplyDesc = FullOptions.map(function (o) { return o[7] });
      applyValidationtoCell(listToApplyDesc,cell);


    }
}

function applyValidationtoCell(list,cell){
  var rule = SpreadsheetApp
  .newDataValidation()
  .requireValueInList(list)
  .setAllowInvalid(false)
  .build();


cell.setDataValidation(rule);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In this:

```
var cell = ws.getRange(r,OptionDesc);
var FullOptions = ws.getRange(r, 2, 1, 7).getValues();
var listToApplyDesc = FullOptions.map(function (o) { return o[7] });
applyValidationtoCell(listToApplyDesc,cell);
```

There is no `o[7]`.  `o[6]` is the last value in that array.  There is 7 columns in the range and therefore there 0 to 6 indices in the array.

Comment: Cooper, as soon as you pointed that out I realized I was using the wrong script. I eliminated that and used a multi condition Filter instead.

Unfortunately, the user has to fill out ALL of the Options to get any Items, which makes the whole thing less than user friendly. To be useful, it should give a list of Items even with partial info. But I think I should probably Ask a new question for that instead of piling onto this one.